# Using rss in Qbittorrent

Tags: 14.04, bittorrent, qbittorrent, rss, torrent-client

How to make qbittorent download episode as soon as it's out there? what are rss rules for instance? I'm kinda lost on that section

I don't want to download previous episodes, otherwise I'll end up downloading trillions of mythbusters videos.

I get feed from http://showrss.info

Edit, I learnt one thing or two from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0LRn2Zdh9M) but not everything so my question still stands, I have yet to figure out how to ignore previous episodes.

I want to download small files from eztv, usually they are something like .LOL.HDTV and the episode is around 230mb, I don't want to download 1gb episodes.

For example if you go to [24](https://kickass.to/24-tv2445/) and click `Episode 12 Day 9: 10:00 PM-11:00 AM`

the torrent I download `24 S09E12 HDTV x264-LOL[ettv]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an old bug in qBittorrent client which is not yet marked as fixed. Look at [Automated download from RSS problematic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qbittorrent/+bug/928613)  and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/1d78ns/qbittorrent_and_eprss_downloader.)

So here are a couple of routes you could try to get those torrents:
 1. Use KTorrent with the Syndication plugin. You can define filters ( .LOL.HDTV ) and how ofter you want to refresh the rss (like qBittorrent.) And afaik this does not have the qBittorrent bug.
 2. If you must stick to qBitTorrent, then taking a cue from the 2nd link above, you could 
 a.) first [setup FlexGet](http://flexget.com/wiki/InstallWizard/Linux)

b.) List items you want to download into a configuration file. Here's a [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZupthYLZ5Q) for it. This tutorial uses the same showrss site as you want. 
Basically, here you provide a folder where all .torrent files would be downloaded, e.g. ~/.torrent

c.) the init the flexget `flexget --initdb`

d.) In your qBittorrent settings, select automatically select torrents from ~/.torrent.

e.) Schedule flexget to run every few minutes and along with it start the qbittorrent client. This can be done using Gnome-Schedule and a simple script file rss.sh. Put the below content in the rss.sh file:

```
 
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/flexget #start flexget to download all .torrent files from rss
export DISPLAY=:0.0 #required to run gui apps such as qBitTorrent
/usr/bin/qbittorrent #run qb, which will pick up .torrent files from the ~/.torrent folder
```

In gnome-schedule, set the above script file. And you are good to go. Here's the tutorial for the [last part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3NyZzMN_Uw).

Make sure that crond service is set to run on bootup and you are good to go.

Comment: could you explain a bit about ktorrent feed filter? I tried adding this filter `HDTV x264-FUM[ettv]` to `mythbusters` series  http://showrss.info/feeds/46.rss, doesn't seem to work

Comment: This link gives out magnet links. Magnet links do not show full filename until a peer connects to it. Hence, KTorrent or any other client can only filter out based on the Title provided in the RSS feed. The filter `HDTV x264-FUM[ettv]` will not work. Instead, you can use a torrent downloader like `Vuze` with `RSSFeed Scanner plugin` which allows filtering by max size.